# what is an organic compound that can meet these conditions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

im looking for a gaseous substance (or airborne solid like dust) to use in my story that is organic, has a sweet odor, or at least pleasant enough to not cause any suspicion from main characters, is nontoxic to inhale, has some coloration (whether that be changing the color of a substance it dissolves in, being visible in the air, or having colored condensation), and is combustive enough to explode from some reaction (preferably with oxygen and high pressure/heat) while not active enough to react with other gasses in the atmosphere. one substance i've found that seems close to what i'm looking for is benzene but due to having no coloration and being harmful from prolonged exposure doesn't seem to be quite what i need. thank you! (edit: from what ive been told having all of the features desired but not required isnt possible so please stop saying what i want is impossible and instead just try to have as many as possible, im not looking for all of them im looking for most of them)

Comment: Benzene does not meet the safety requirements.,too. It is a powerful carcinogen.

Comment: What do you mean with "my story" ? Are you a writer ? Substances that are both gaseous and colored are not numerous : $\ce{Br2, NO2, Cl2, ClO2}$. They are all toxic and corrosive. Furthermore they cannot burn. So I am afraid the substance you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: @Maurice i am actually but i felt this was not fitting for the other stack exchange branches, also i did allow solid airborne particles as well as gasses if that makes it easier.

Comment: @zackit. I repeat : what do you mean with "my story" ? Are you writing a novel ? a science fiction ? Has it to make sense ? Because you will never find a non-toxic substance which has a color, a pleasant odor, and may explode when mixed in air.

Comment: @Maurice its not science fiction, and i said "preferably with oxygen" it doesn't have to be oxygen. also, it doesn't need to color the air, just have some sort of coloration. please reread and pay attention to what is required and what is preferred.

Comment: If we share the same notion of perfume, then the likelihood of a finely dispersed aerosol behind a person, an animal, an object to meet all of your criteria is slim.  If the characters of your plot posses a better protected respiration system, than the typical human being, they may find the fumes of nitric acid beautiful (e. g., Derek Lowe's [How Not to Do It](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2015/12/21/how-not-to-do-it-transporting-nitric-acid)).

Comment: Your best bet is probably some finely divided dust. Many finely divided dust particles (eg flour, coal, wood) can explode given a suitable trigger. So there may be one which is also coloured (and there are few *volatile* substances that have much colour so dust is the way to go).

Comment: Custard powder? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGBT5pwxThU

Comment: The way you treat language, I do not believe you are a writer; I do, however, believe that the bounty you have offered prevented closure of this question. To be honest, I would treat this the same way as I would treat homework. You have not offered any own research. Additionally, you have failed to present your query well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benzene, which has already been mentioned in the comments is colourless. The frequency of light absorbed corresponds to the complementary colour of the colour we see in azo dyes. Benzene only contains a small area of delocalisation, which is not sufficient to lower the energy gap to the visible part of the spectrum, meaning benzene absorbs UV light and is **colourless**. On the other hand, It has a **sweet odour** and is **highly flammable**. Benzene evaporates into the air very quickly. Its vapour is heavier than air and may sink into low-lying areas.

NOTE: benzene may possess a **pale yellow colour** at room temperature.

Also, though benzene is deadly in case of long-term exposure (Long-term exposure means exposure of a year or more) and causes harmful effects on the bone marrow and can cause a decrease in red blood cells, leading to anaemia, Acute (short-term) inhalation exposure of humans to benzene causes no more than a bit of **drowsiness, dizziness or headaches**, in relatively lesser concentrations

Comment: with this extra information about benzene, i feel the substance i'm looking for may be some solution composed of benzene and a few other substances. though it does not provide a complete answer for what it i will mark this correct anyway as it is seemingly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Given that I am a new member and don't have much reputation, I can't comment on your post, so I am answering here...ozone has a pale bluish colour and also a metallic odour and if it is present in minimal concentration it is not deadly toxic, just might result in chest pain and laboured breathing...In the stratosphere, ozone is formed when a molecule of oxygen absorbs a photon of light with wavelengths shorter than 200nm, is split into atomic oxygen and the atomic oxygen reacts with an oxygen molecule to form ozone, but i am not sure whether it is volatile or not..however, ground-level ozone is formed by reaction betweeen oxides of nitrogen and VOCs (volatile organic compounds)

Comment: Why not edit your first answer and add this to it?

Comment: Because they're different solutions or something

Comment: Actually you have enough rep to comment now, so perhaps you could delete the answer and comment instead (with 86 characters removed if you can: just remove the unnecessary dots, definition of VOC, extra 'u' in odor, maybe call nitrogen "N" and oxygen "O", etc.).

Comment: Yes, now I have enough rep, earlier I had 1 rep when I posted this,,, but what is the advantage of doing that - deleting this and commenting?